# lazy compiler/debugger?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

i'm searching for hours now, to get a solution for this problem:

at the very beginning of my android app, a layout with buttons is shown to the user. if he clicks on the button "Tasks" a listView should pop up (another activity and layout) to show him all available Tasks, and with a click on one he can do even more things, but they're not necessary for my problem. the point is, the app won't get any Data out of the Database, but when I **Step Into** or **Step Over** the lines which call a method for all the DBStuff it works. 
Here are the necesssary lines:

```
 if (connection1.OpenDatabase(1, getDataBaseName()))
        {
            CTask = connection1.DBQueryTable(getDataBaseName(), "Tasks", TempFieldT);
            CEquipment = connection1.DBQueryTable(getDataBaseName(), "Equipment", TempFieldE);
            connection1.CloseDatabase();
        }
```

so he will run over those lines, execute the lines beneath, but wont give any Data back, when i'm not supervising it with breakpoints, and the steps. when i do it, all things work the way they should.

The Database Stuff the app runs through at this place.

```
public Android.Database.ICursor DBQueryTable(string DataBaseName, string TableName, string[] Fields)
    {
        FindDBPath(DataBaseName);
        Android.Database.ICursor c;
        string TempF = "";
        string str = "";
        foreach (string n in Fields)
        { TempF += n + ","; }
        SQLQuery = "SELECT " + (str = TempF.TrimEnd(',')) +" FROM " + TableName;
        c = sqldTemp.RawQuery(SQLQuery, null);
        return c;        
    }
```

so why do the app/compiler/debugger behave like this? are there any mistakes i did, but i can't figure out right now?

Ps: yeah i know there is a query function, but thats not necessary here as long as it would provide a solution to my problem.

Comment: Are these database calls synchronous/blocking or asynchronous?

Comment: hmm i can't tell you which type they are... because i don't know what synchronous or asyncs calls would be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `DBQueryTable` method returns a *cursor*. That will become invalidated as soon as you close the connection in the following line:

```
connection1.CloseDatabase();
```

You should keep the connection open for as long as you need the cursor. For example, you could fetch all the data from the cursor and *then* close the connection.

Comment: i thought that this line would keep al the data even though the cursor is closed by CloseDatabase(), because i'm saving it in another cursor?

CEquipment = connection1.DBQueryTable(getDataBaseName(), "Equipment", TempFieldE);

Comment: @EaranMaleasi: What do you mean by "another cursor"? Do you understand that the whole point of a cursor is that it only reads data as it needs to? How do you expect it to read the data after the connection has been closed?

Comment: CTask and CEquipment are of type Android.Database.ICursor...and if i'm understanding the first two lines, the app calls my DBQueryTable method, which returns a cursor, which is saved in one of those two, CTask and CEquipment. all data was read and saved.... or am i that wrong with cursors.

Comment: @EaranMaleasi: I don't have experience with *Android* cursors - but in "normal" database systems, a cursor is associated with an *open* connection. Just as an experiment, *try* removing the `CloseDatabase` call. Obviously at some point you'll need to work out when to close it, but humour me, just to validate whether this really is the problem. (As an aside, `CTask` and `CEquipment` are very unconventional as variable names...)

Comment: I'll try that, next time i'm at work and will respond whether it worked or not. i named the variables of what they are, C = Cursor and where they get their data from... what would be more conventional?

Comment: @EaranMaleasi: Well not Pascal-cased to start with - and I'd personally go for `taskData` and `equipmentData` for example.

Comment: maybe I'll change it sometime. now i've moved the CloseDatabase Function to a later part of the activity, when the Data is shown in a GridView. now the whole thing works perfectly with my Test data. thanks for your help.

Comment: @EaranMaleasi: An alternative is to open the connection, explicitly fetch all the data, and then immediately close the connection. I'm glad it's working though.